# Using tmux and pbpaste, pbcopy, and launchctl

Tags: terminal, iterm, launchd

I have discovered that [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) breaks `pbpaste`, `pbcopy` and `launchctl`.

Is there a good way to make it play nice with these tools?

Answer (score 33):

Okay, I found a solution...

Chris Johnsen has a [good writeup](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) of what causes this problem on github.

His tools work, but a better solution, if you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed to:

```
brew install reattach-to-user-namespace
```

Then in your `~/.tmux.conf` add these lines:

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh" # or bash
bind C-c run "tmux show-buffer | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
bind C-v run "reattach-to-user-namespace pbpaste | tmux load-buffer - && tmux paste-buffer"
```

The first line ensures your shell can talk to `pbpaste`, `pbcopy` and `launchctl` now with no worries.

The second line lets you copy the `tmux` paste buffer into the Mac's paste buffer by typing <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> (replace <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> with your tmux prefix key).

The third line will directly paste the Mac's paste buffer by typing <kbd>control-v</kbd>.  As a side-effect it copies the Mac's paste buffer into `tmux`'s paste buffer.

I'd prefer if I could nuke `tmux`'s paste buffer entirely and have it paste directly into the Mac`s paste buffer, but... oh well.